# Are there any restrictions for bath salts (magnesium flakes) in hand luggage flying within Europe?

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, ryanair, gifts

In some sources it is written that you can carry bath salts:

- [Carrying powder-type stuff in carry on - problems?](https://www.tripadvisor.ie/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k4706811-o20-Carrying_powder_type_stuff_in_carry_on_problems-Air_Travel.html)
- [Banned on board: Christmas gifts you can’t take on a flight:](https://www.skyscanner.net/news/banned-onboard-the-christmas-gifts-you-cant-travel-with)

> Bath bombs are also allowed, but call them ‘bath salts’ in the
>   airport, to avoid any misunderstandings at security!

But there are opposite articles:

- [Transport Canada to ban large containers of bath salts and baby powder in carry-on luggage](http://www.rcinet.ca/en/2017/11/07/transport-canada-to-ban-large-containers-of-bath-salts-and-baby-powder-in-carry-on-luggage/)
- [ryanair hand luggage restrictions - NON-LIQUID toiletries:](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124085/ryanair-hand-luggage-restrictions-non-liquid-toiletries)

> Returning from Nantes to Edinburgh yesterday on Ryanair, my 200g
>   canister of sea salts for a foot bath was confiscated. I knew there
>   was a 100 ml limit on liquids, obviously, but I can't find any
>   information on the Ryanair site which mentions any restrictions on
>   non-liquid toiletries.
>
> The guy said I should have decanted the salts into two 100 ml bottles.
>   I offered to decant them into two plastic bags, but he said it was the
>   size of the container that counted, not the contents.

Do you have any experience with bath salts / magnesium flakes in hand luggage flying within Europe? If it is allowed, what's the limit for hand luggage?

Comment: The airline doesn't screen your hand luggage, the local airport security or government transit security organization does. Which airports are you flying to and from?

Comment: From Dublin to Vilnius.

Comment: At least in the US, "bath salts" is a common street name for a group of synthetic drugs of abuse, so I would not necessarily use that term with law enforcement either...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'LAG' restrictions enforced throughout much of the world cover Liquids, Aerosols, and Gels.  Whilst the definition of these can be a little vague (is Peanut Butter really a Gel?), dried "salts" fairly clearly do not fit into any of these categories.

I have traveled with bath salts > 100ml/100grams  in my carry-on bags in the past and have never had a problem.  On one occasion the airport security staff did ask to see them as they were not able to determine from the X-ray what they were, but once they confirmed what they were then I was let through without any issues.

The US TSA "Can I Bring" website doesn't have a specific entry for Bath Salts (which is a good sign, as if they were disallowed it most likely would), but does have "[salt](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/salt)" which is allowed with no size/volume restrictions.

Just as a warning, be aware that "bath salts" is also the street name for an illegal class of Synthetic cathinone drugs. They have this name because they have a crystalline form that resembles normal bath salts.

Comment: My baggage was inspected by TSA at SFO (cabin) and in JFK (checked, they have left inspection note wrapped around salt bottle).

Answer (score 1):

There was no problem with 1kg magnesium flakes for cabin baggage. Security staff didn't know about the restrictions.